# Playing video's audio in background during screen off, android?

Tags: android, audio, video-streaming, exoplayer, mediabrowserservicecompat

I have an application which uses exoplayer to play videos.

When the user is on player page and presses the power button to close the screen I want the audio to keep playing in the background and notification should be visible to user with controls of play, pause , video metadata etc similar to what we have for every music playing app.

I can keep the audio of video playing from exoplayer using `setPlayWhenReady(true)`.

But I am stuck in for notification. Should I be using `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` or I will have to create custom notification to handle it?

Comment: post your code here

Comment: So, how did you made audio play, when screen off ?

Comment: @karticchaudhary you can use player notification manager for this. https://medium.com/google-exoplayer/playback-notifications-with-exoplayer-a2f1a18cf93b

Answer (score 0):

I think what you should do is to create ForegroundService and create notification as you mentioned to have the ForegroundService working. I think this post might help you:

https://androidwave.com/foreground-service-android-example/

Answer (score 0):

Use a foreground service to implement something like this.[This](https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service) can help you